# Simulate drawing marbles from a bag with replacement time efficiently

Tags: distributions, simulation, uniform-distribution

I have a bag with 256 marbles, each a different color. Everytime I run the experiment, I have a 1/16 chance of drawing any marble. I can simulate this by instead considering a bag with 16×256 marbles, and drawing from that bag everytime I run the experiment. The trouble comes when I want to run the experiment an arbitrary amount of times. I want to run it n times and record the amount of times that each marble was chosen. If I have to run the experiment 1 million times (which will be very likely), I want a way to make it so simulating the n experiments depends only on the size of the bag of the 256 marbles, and not the size of n.

My initial idea was to use a binomial distribution on each marble. I wanted to simulate the amount of successes for a marble. This would be done under a binomial distribution with probability of success 1/16^3 and a sample size of k. We generate a number of successes m, and then when we generate the next marble, we use the same probability but instead use a sample size of k-m. We repeatedly widle down the sample size until we exhaust the marbles or we exhaust the sample size, whichever comes first. But the issue is that I'm not confident that this actually reflects my original intent.

How can I simulate this scenario efficiently?

Comment: Is your experiment drawing $16$ marbles without replacement from a bag of $16^2=256$ marbles?  Otherwise, I find it difficult to understand *"I have a bag with $256$ marbles, each a different color. Everytime I run the experiment, I have a $1/16$ chance of drawing any marble."*

Comment: In R you could try `set.seed(2021); sims<-replicate(10^6,sample(256,16)); table(sims)` and find that each of the $256$ tends to be sampled about $62500$ times, plus or minus a bit of random noise. It takes about $6$ seconds on my machine to do the million simulations and another $2$ seconds to construct the table of results

Comment: My experiment is drawing a marble from a bag 1 million times with replacement. The 1/16 part is about the fact that in this particular experiment, each time I try to draw a marble, there's a 15/16 chance that I "miss". As in, I can technically still draw 1 million marbles, but I'm probably going to end up drawing around 1 mil÷16 marbles.

Comment: Then `sims<-ifelse(runif(10^6)>1/16,0,1)*sample(256,10^6,replace=TRUE); table(sims)` might do want you want more quickly, putting close to $937500$ cases into colour $0$ (failure to draw a coloured marble) and about $244$ plus or minus some randomness into each of the $256$ numbered colours